# How to replace the custom post type slug with other post name on url in wordpress?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

i have a url which is working given below 
Eg: (working)
www.domain.com/post-type/postname
www.domain.com/offer/get-free-20-rs

Now i want to replace that url 
like this 
Eg:- (unworking)
www.domain.com/brandname/postname
 www.domain.com/paytm/get-free-20-rs

when i replaced the first url (www.domain.com/offer/get-free-20-rs )with second url (www.domain.com/paytm/get-free-20-rs ) then it goes to 404 error page.

Basically post_type replace with other post type name.

But i got this Url  but problem is goes to 404 error page.

So how to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have no page on this url. It goes to 404 because there is no post or page against this page. You have to edit this page www.domain.com/offer/get-free-20-rs using the edit url options that is displayed on the post to this www.domain.com/paytm/get-free-20-rs